# How to build sub module's child module via maven build argument

Tags: java, maven

Here's my project structure:

```
 ├── module_1
     ├── sub_module
          ├── module_11
          ├── module_12
          ├── module_13
 ├── module_2
```

Now if I build it with the following command:

```
$~ mvn package -pl sub_module
```

It would only build **sub_module** but not its children module.

The only way to build `module_11/module_12/module_13` is to specify them explicitly as following:

```
$~ mvn package -pl sub_module,sub_module/module_11,sub_module/module_12,sub_module/module_13
```

This is inconvenient for me, just wondering if there is an easier way approach this?

Comment: If the submodule pom.xml includes a module section with module_1x list, it should build those.

Comment: I have that in sub_module pom.xml, but it still only build sub_module, but not its children modules.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check if adding the `-am` or `-amd` option helps

```
mvn clean package -pl sub_module -am
mvn clean package -pl sub_module -amd  <== (confirmed by the OP)
```

see at [Maven Tips and Tricks: Advanced Reactor Options](https://blog.sonatype.com/2009/10/maven-tips-and-tricks-advanced-reactor-options/):

> ```
> -am, --also-make
> ```

> If project list is specified, also build projects required by the list

> ```
> -amd, --also-make-dependents
> ```

> If project list is specified, **also build projects that depend on projects on the list**.

Comment: Although it works for me, it doesn't work perfectly. --amd would also build other projects depend on this sub_module, but what I want to is to build all child modules under this sub_module

Comment: Even if it "works" for the OP, it does not answer to the question since it provides a way to build everything which depends on the "sub-module" children, and not only these "sub-module" children. I am also looking for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've got two kludges that may fit:

Run build on specific pom file using `-f`:

```
$ mvn package -f module_1/submodule
```

Or `cd` into required module and simply build it:

```
$ pwd
/module_1
$ cd submodule
$ mvn package
```

It, howewer, takes more pain moving across directories.